# #VALUE! error using excel 2016 nested IF statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, troubleshooting, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting, data-analysis

I'm unable to perform a simple nested IF statement on this data, the conditional seems perfect to me so it must be a formatting error or something else. I'm new to excel so I could be wrong.

This is the conditional.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What's the value of P3?

Comment: Most likely P3,D4, or E4 have and empty string `""` being returned.  One cannot do math on strings.

Comment: Change the O3 to O4? Try this formula: =IF(O4="LONG SPY";P3*(1+E4);IF(O4="LONG GLD";P3*(1+D4);P3))

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many parentheses after the (1+E4) piece. I'm far from proficient with Excel formulas but I was tinkering a bit and that seemed to fix it for me.

Barring that I also thought it was odd that you have semicolons to separate each term in the IF statement. I've always used commas.

Comment: I removed some parentheses and it fixed it up! Thank you! And the semi colons are for excel 2016

Comment: That makes sense. I primarily use the old school 2010 version.

Comment: The semicolons are always used as an alternative in countries where comma is already used for decimal number separator by convention eg 1/10 = 0.1 shown as 0,1
This is not related to the Excel version.